# Spring Environment class - loading properties value with dynamic key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, properties, environment

Is there any limitation with `Environment` class to load properties dynamically?

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

environment.getProperty("spring.data".concat(dynamickey);
```

I have 2 dependent projects.
Both projects are having `applicationcontext.xml` with class path mentioned to read properties files based on environment like dev,uat,live ...etc.

In both the projects in one of the class i have initialised `Environment` class to read the properties.
Unfortunately in both the places environment class loaded same properties.if i debug i can see same properties in both places.

My requirement is to load the properties differently in both the places.

Can some one please help me to resolve the issue?

Some more information regarding above query:

i have 2 projects

```
Project A:
  src
     java
        ---- Test1.java
     resources
        ----dev.properties
        ----uat.properties
        ----live.properties
        ----applicationcontext.xml -- contains bean with classpath

Project B:
  src
     java
        ---- Test2.java
     resources
        ----dev.properties
        ----uat.properties
        ----live.properties
        ----applicationcontext.xml -- contains bean with classpath
```

Test1.java contains

```
class Test1{
   @Autowired
   private Environment environment;

  public void abc(String val){
    String aaa=environment.getProperty("address.".concat(val));
  }

}
```

Test2.java contains

```
class Test2{
   @Autowired
   private Environment environment;

  public void abc(String val){
    String bbb=environment.getProperty("address.".concat(val));
  }

}
```

when i am debugging Test2.java, the environment is having project A properties instead Project B properties.

Is there any way that i can load Project A properties to Test1.java Environment object and Project B properties to Test2.java Environment Object.

Comment: I think you should have different properties files for different environments, then you would not bother about concating some terms like "dev" or "uat".

Comment: Looks like you are working around the default support in Spring Boot. Use the framework don't hack around it.

Comment: Are those 2 different projects with separated source ?

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi yes

Comment: you've said "when i am debugging Test2.java, the environment is having project A properties instead Project B properties." Are you sure that the content of both sides are different ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Profiles in spring, and there is multiple ways to do it :

**1. Use properties based profile :**

Create multiple properties files ( application-dev.properties, application-prod.properties, with an application.properties that serves as default profile ) then run your app with -Dspring.profiles.active= dev for example.

**2. Use Yaml based profiles (application.yml) :**

[image]

There is more options to do the same things

**Note** : I couldn't format the yaml code correctly in my response that's why I've attached a picture

Comment: Hi, Can you please help me if you have any idea about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After spending lot of time we came to know that Environment is loading the properties from both the projects.

If keys in the properties are different then there will not be any issue,if the keys in the properties files are same then will get the propertu from first loaded properties file.